# Ideas to send the result of a SQL Select as MailMessage body in ASP.NET MailMessage Class

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

So let's say I have this select : `SELECT TITLES FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE AC_DATE = GETDATE()`

In my .cs code it will be like this

```
con.Open();
string query = "SELECT TITLES FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE AC_DATE = GETDATE()"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

It will return some Titles from my table. I need to insert all these records that came from my select on `mailMessage.Body = "";` To send to some people via Email, but how would I do that?

Comment: Do you know how to send email via C#? How much of the code do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the results in a SqlDataReader and add the titles to a string.

```
//create a stringbuilder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//create a connection to the database 
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TITLES FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE AC_DATE = GETDATE()", connection))
{
    //open the connection
    connection.Open();

    //create a reader
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    //loop all the rows in the database
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //add the title to the stringbuilder
        sb.AppendLine(reader["TITLES"].ToString());
    }
}

//create the mail message with the titles
mailMessage.Body = sb.ToString();
```